# Inline Assembly lea with arrays

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly, inline-assembly

Hello I have a question about the lea instruction and arrays, This works fine:

```
char *msg = new char[6];
msg = "hello";

_asm{
    push        10h
    push        0
    mov         eax, [msg]
    push        eax
    push        0
    call        MessageBox
     }
```

}

But why do I get an "operand size conflict" error here?

```
char msg2[] = "hey2";
_asm{
    push        10h
    push        0
    mov         eax, [msg2]
    push        eax
    push        0
    call        MessageBox
}
```

And why does it work again with lea?

```
char msg2[] = "hey2";
_asm{
    push        10h
    push        0
    lea         eax, [msg2]  // <-
    push        eax
    push        0
    call        MessageBox
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are trying to dereference the pointer which points to size char, but you try to load an int from it.

```
mov         eax, [msg2]
```

Not sure if this is the right syntax, but you might use

```
mov   eax, offset msg3
```

here, to load the address, or use the `lea` instruction.

In C this would be similar to:

```
char msg2[10];
char *p = &msg2[0];
int x = *p;
```

This instruction doesn't dereference the pointer, it just takes the address of it and it can also calculate addresses with certain operators.

```
lea         eax, [msg2]  // <-
```

Is aequivalent of:

```
char msg2[10];
char *p = &msg2[0];
```

Comment: The `mov` instructions moves data between source and target. Since the size doesn't match byte <> dword you get an error.